# Is it possible to force Windows 7 VPN client to ignore the local network?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, vpn, pptp

I have a PPTP VPN server which I connect to using Windows 7's built in VPN client. I was hoping that the behavior of the VPN client would be such that it would appear that I am physically connected to the local network the VPN connects to. For example, lets say that the network that I am *actually* physically connected to uses the 192.168.1.* subnet and that the VPN network uses the 192.168.0.* subnet. The behavior I am hoping for is that when I am connected to the VPN, an attempt to access 192.168.1.1 should fail as all traffic goes to the VPN network, and the VPN network only knows about 192.168.1.* addresses.

This is, unfortunately, not the way the Windows VPN client behaves by default. Is there a way to force this behavior? I have checked the VPN connection settings but have found nothing.

EDIT: A clarification of a situation I want to avoid: if the VPN network and the physical network use the same subnet and I try to access an IP address that exists on both networks, I will get the interface that exist on the local physical network. I want to get the interface on the VPN network.

Comment: So you want traffic that's destined for 192.168.0.1 (on the VPN's subnet) to fail whenever you are connected to the VPN? You my want to recheck the example IPs/subnets in your question, it doesn't make much sense as-is.

Comment: Your question is confusing.  A VPN client DOES make you part of the private network on the server side, hence the Virtual Private Network name.  So what are you trying to do?

Comment: techie007: Oops, I obviously mixed up the subnets in the example. Edited the question.

Comment: surfasb: Made a clarification in the question.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is impossible. If you were able to ignore the local network totally, how would you find the default gateway to even route to your VPN?

What is your real intent, I may be able to help you with that. In other words, why would you care about seeing your local network in the first place, and what is your real concern?

Comment: The local network connection would still be able to access the local network as usual. The VPN connection sitting on top of the local network connection would however override the normal local network connection when an application tries to access the network. I have used VPN clients that behave this way (not sure which ones but I do believe Cisco behaves like this).